# Focus ListView Items on Button Click

Tags: android, listview, button, focus

[image]Is it possible to focus the List View Items through any button click? 
Like i want that when user click on Floating Action Button then the listview gets focused. I dont want to show checkbox type layout on button clicked. I just want to show the same like in the screenshot on Button click.
What i did is I put the listview onItemLongClick code in the button click blocks but it doesnot work.

```
 fabButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        listViewMessages.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        listViewMessages.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
                                              long id, boolean checked) {

                tv.setText(listViewMessages.getCheckedItemCount()+ " Selected");



            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(final ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.menu:

                            }
                          });
                        mode.finish();
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu for the CAB
                MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.contextual, menu);

                fabButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                fabButtonn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                fabButtonn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        for ( int i=0; i< messageListAdapter.getCount(); i++ ) {
                            listViewMessages.setItemChecked(i, true);
                    }

                    }
                });
                return true;
            }


            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
                fabButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                fabButtonn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                // Here you can perform updates to the CAB due to
                // an invalidate() request
                return false;
            }
        });
```

With this code if user clcik on button then he/she has too long press items again to focus the list items which is not what i want. I want to focus items right when button click. Any explanation or link provided will be helpful